# OO: new class implementing requires additional parameter

Tags: java, oop

let's say i have an interface as below

```
public interface ConditionChecker {
    boolean isInCondition(Person p);
}
```

I want to create a new class implementing the above interface but i need to implement a function with another parameter

```
public class MacroConditionChecker implements ConditionChecker {
    public boolean isInCondition(Person p, MacroView mv);
}
```

Two problems:
One: if i change the interface signature to `boolean isInCondition(Person p, MacroView mv);` then i need to update all the classes implementing ConditionChecker
Two: I want the consumers of ConditionChecker to just call isInCondition as-is

I think that means:

```
public class MacroConditionChecker implements ConditionChecker {
    private static final MacroView mv;
    public MacroConditionChecker(MacroView mv) {
        this.mv = mv;
    }
    public boolean isInCondition(Person p){
        // now i have access to MacroView
    }
}
```

so, the only change i need is make at the time I decide to use MacroConditionChecker and the call to isInCondition is not changed

Am i on the right track? or Is there some way else to accomplish this?

or should i separate out MacroView as its own interface

```
public class MacroConditionChecker implements ConditionChecker implements MacroView
```

Comment: This is one of the possible solution indeed. But then it has an unnecessary sort of permanent state.. What if you just make a new method in the interface which calls an overloaded method with the default qualifier?

Comment: Your first solution is pretty good. But why did you declare `mv` field as static?

Comment: @YassinHajaj could you elaborate further? not 100% following

Comment: Are you passing multiple `ConditionChecker` classes into a function, and then looping over them calling `isInCondition` to check all the conditions at once? That would explain your desire to not change that interface. Is so, I think your solution works well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ConditionChecker` reminds [`Command` design pattern](https://sourcemaking.com/design_patterns/command). Comment from the linked page:

> Command decouples the object that invokes the operation from the one
>   that knows how to perform it. To achieve this separation, the designer
>   creates an abstract base class that maps a receiver (an object) with
>   an action (a pointer to a member function). The base class contains an
>   execute() method that simply calls the action on the receiver.

This is exactly, what you need. In case you need to check only internal state of `Person` object it is enough. When you want to check `Person` object with external `API` that's OK to create implementation which binds external `API` in constructor with `Person` object in method. Simple example:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class DesignPatterns {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<ConditionChecker> checkers = new ArrayList<>();
        checkers.add(person -> person != null);
        checkers.add(person -> person.getName() != null);
        checkers.add(person -> person.getName().length() > 0);
        checkers.add(new MacroViewConditionChecker(new MacroView()));
        checkers.add(new RestApiConditionChecker(new RestApi()));

        Person person = new Person();
        person.setName("Name");

        for (ConditionChecker checker : checkers) {
            System.out.println(checker.isInCondition(person));
        }
    }
}

interface ConditionChecker {

    boolean isInCondition(Person person);
}

class MacroViewConditionChecker implements ConditionChecker {

    private final MacroView macroView;

    public MacroViewConditionChecker(MacroView macroView) {
        this.macroView = macroView;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isInCondition(Person person) {
        return macroView != null;
    }
}

class MacroView {
}

class RestApiConditionChecker implements ConditionChecker {

    private final RestApi restApi;

    public RestApiConditionChecker(RestApi restApi) {
        this.restApi = restApi;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isInCondition(Person person) {
        return restApi.checkName(person.getName());
    }
}

class RestApi {

    public boolean checkName(String name) {
        System.out.println("Validate name ...");
        System.out.println(name + " is valid");

        return true;
    }
}

class Person {

    private String name;

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
}
```

You can use this pattern together with [Chain of Responsibility](https://sourcemaking.com/design_patterns/chain_of_responsibility). This approach does not bind `Person` object with any implementation. This bind is done in specific `ConditionChecker` implementation which can be easily exchanged.

Answer (score 1):

Given that `MacroConditionChecker` cannot respect the `ConditionChecker` signature, then what's the point of implementing it?

Maybe a better approach is to transform the `MacroConditionChecker` `class` to an `interface` which **extends** `ConditionChecker`

```
interface MacroConditionChecker extends ConditionChecker {
   boolean isInCondition(final Person person, final MacroView macroView);
}
```

And then provide a default/simple implementation (or whatever you need)

```
class SimpleMacroConditionChecker implements MacroConditionChecker {
   public boolean isInCondition(final Person person, final MacroView macroView) {
      ...
   }
}
```

The ones that needs to check a condition using a `MacroView` will simply accept a `MacroConditionChecker`

```
public boolean check(final MacroConditionChecker checker) {
   return checker.isInCondition(this.person, this.macroView);
}
```

---

<strike>Personally, I see them as two totally separated `interface`s, but the extension approach is still good.</strike>
Choose cautiously, especially if they'll be used in many places.

Comment: i dont think this solves the second problem i've mentioned. let's say I have many objects using ConditionalChecker and calling isInCondition. If it uses MacroConditionChecker i now need to go make changes to all the places where isInCondition.  And if i roll back MacroConditionChecker, i need to make the same changes again. I am trying to minize so that i can replace the logic for ConditionChecker seamlessly

Comment: @ealeon as I said, if someone need the additional MacroView for the check, than it should accept a MacroConditionChecker. That is the most idiomatic and correct approach. So yes, you'll have to refactor

Answer (score 1):

Since the interface is only asking that you implement the given method, you could overload the method with the parameters that you desire, and the appropriate implementation will run when an extra parameter is passed.

```
public class MacroConditionChecker implements ConditionChecker {
    boolean isInCondition(Person p) {};
    public boolean isInCondition(Person p, MacroView mv) {};
}
```

Comment: but this doesnt solve the second problem that i've mentioned that the consumers of ConditionChecker need to now call with an additional parameters. For example, if i decide that i MacroConditionChecker is no longer default, I need to go all the places and make changes so that it calls with only one argument, right?

Comment: Java is smart enough to call the method that matches that object's class and to use the method implementation that matches the parameters that are passed to it during the call. What this will do is simply allow you to call isInCondition on MacroConditionChecker objects with two parameters as input, it won't change anything outside of the class, nor will it affect other calls that only use a 'Person' as input.

Comment: "What this will do is simply allow you to call isInCondition on MacroConditionChecker objects with two parameters as input" this is the exact change I am trying to avoid. If i have 1000 objects now wanting to use MacroConditionChecker isInCondition, i dont want to make 1000 changes

Comment: This would allow you to avoid creating the 1000 objects and setting the MacroView for all of them during creation, and instead create a single object that deals with any MacroView that you wish to check.

Comment: not if i want MacroConditionChecker as a default and that only subset ConditionChecker consumers use different ConditionChecker with one parameter. the point is i shouldnt need to make any changes to the consumers of ConditionChecker, no?